# Does blowup induce an isomorphism on relative homology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $f : X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism with $Z\subset Y$ a closed set, such that $f$ induces an isomorphism $X - f^{-1}(Z)\cong Y-Z$.

Are there reasonable hypotheses under which we can deduce that $f$ induces an isomorphism on relative homology $H_*(X,f^{-1}(Z))\cong H_*(Y,Z)$?

Here, I'm thinking of $f$ as the blowup of a complex algebraic variety (possibly with singularities).

Comment: Assuming you mean all the right things (there are a few details missing), shouldn't the answer be always in the case that this is a blowup? Both pairs of spaces are good pairs and the quotients should be the same, right?

Comment: @KReiser Ah, good point. I now see why they are abstractly isomorphic. I suppose it's still not clear to me that the morphism $f$ should induce an isomorphism, but perhaps it's obvious when one delves into the isomorphism between relative homology and the reduced homology of the quotient...